# How to configure Jest in PhpStorm for React application (create-react-app flavor)

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, phpstorm

I'm trying to run tests from within PhpStorm IDE. But IDE throws an error and doesn't accept my configuration as valid. Although I configured it as [official PhpStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/running-unit-tests-on-jest.html) explains it.

I have standard CRA application. I want to use Enzyme and Jest as test utils.

I use [jest-enzyme](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/tree/master/packages/jest-enzyme) and [jest-environment-enzyme](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/packages/jest-environment-enzyme) packages along with [enzyme](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme) and **enzyme-adapter-react-16**.

PhpStorm docs says:

> Specify the location of the **jest**, **react-scripts**, **react-script-ts**, **react-super-scripts**, or **react-awesome-scripts** package.

I've tried to specify both, **jest** or **react-scripts**. And both options do not work in PhpStorm.

Here are my two configurations:

**No.1: Jest**

IDE throws SyntaxError because it doesn't recognize React components. I think it doesn't know how to use Babel or Webpack. But IDE documentation doesn't mention anything about how to point IDE to Babel or other compilers.

[image]

**No.2: react-scripts**

IDE throws **argv.config.match is not a function**. It can't even start testing.

[image]

My **jest.config.js** is as follows as it requited by [jest-environment-enzyme](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/enzyme-matchers/blob/master/packages/jest-environment-enzyme):

```
module.exports = {
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["jest-enzyme"],
  "testEnvironment": "enzyme",
  "verbose": true,
};
```

**UPD1:**

My `setupTests.js` file:

```
// jest-dom adds custom jest matchers for asserting on DOM nodes.
// allows you to do things like:
// expect(element).toHaveTextContent(/react/i)
// learn more: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import 'jest-enzyme';

Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});
```

Comment: what command do you use to run your tests when not using the IDE?

Comment: @lena I'm on **create-react-app**, so I run `$ npm run test`. It in turns runs `react-scripts test`

Comment: using the second configuration should work then, it runs `react-scripts test`; can be related to passing the config explicitly (see https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/396, for example). Does it work if you clear the *Configuration file:* field?

Comment: I got rid of configuration completely, both as a separate file and as part of `package.json`. But I added `setupTests.js` file and added Enzyme configuration in there. Please see question UPD1 how my `setupTests.js` looks like now.